# Docker compose does not link with MySQL database correctly

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose which will create a guacamole docker container, a guacd container and a mysql container. On the docker host, I have ithe init.db inside the `/tmp/scripts`

If I was to do the mysql part manually, I would run `docker run --name guac-mysql -v /tmp/scripts:/tmp/scripts -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.7`

Then run the guacamole container like this:

```
docker run --name guacamole --link guacd:guacd --link mysql:mysql \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE='guacamole' \
-e MYSQL_USER='guacamole' \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD='password' \
-d -p 8080:8080 guacamole/guacamole


version: '2'

services:
  guacd:
    hostname: guacd
    image: guacamole/guacd
  mysql:
    hostname: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE="guacamole"
      - MYSQL_USER="guacamole"
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD="password"
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:"password"
  guacamole:
    image: guacamole/guacamole
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - guacd
      - mysql
   environment:
      - GUACD_HOSTNAME=guacd


volumes:
  tmp-scripts:
```

But when I try to automate it, as shown below, I get this error:

```
database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: Change semicolon `:` for `=` after `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`

Comment: That did it thank you so much. Is the volume section correct? Will the content of the /tmp/scripts of the host machine be copied into the mysql container into the /tmp/scripts directory? Thank you

Comment: Volumes section seems correct, give it a few tests to sure it copies the data exactly where you want

Comment: I appreciate your replies. The strange thing is when I exec into the mysql container and try to log into the database as user root and password as set in docker-compose.yml, I get a ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 1):

`:` to `=`
`MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="password"`